FFMPEG: while trying to remove one subtitle, I am getting "Subtitle encoding currently only possible from text to text or bitmap to bitmap"
I know I am using an older version of ffmpeg, but I am receiving an error while trying to remove ONE of the subtitles (0:0). I was able to add a srt subtitle without issue.
I am using the following command:
ffmpeg -i "Movie-hevc.mkv" -map 0 -map -0:s:0 output.mkv
The version is:
ffmpeg version 2023-02-13-git-2296078397-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
The error is as follows:
[sost#0:0/ssa @ 000001ca1f271cc0] Subtitle encoding currently only possible from text to text or bitmap to bitmapError initializing output stream:
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub) -> ass (ssa))
Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub) -> ass (ssa))
Stream #0:3 -> #0:2 (hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub) -> ass (ssa))
Stream #0:4 -> #0:3 (hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub) -> ass (ssa))
Stream #0:5 -> #0:4 (hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub) -> ass (ssa))
Stream #0:6 -> #0:5 (hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub) -> ass (ssa))
Stream #0:7 -> #0:6 (aac (native) -> vorbis (libvorbis))
Stream #0:8 -> #0:7 (hevc (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Stream #0:9 -> #0:8 (subrip (srt) -> ass (ssa))
Last message repeated 1 times
Any idea as to how I can remove the subitle while leaving everything else in tact?
If worse comes to worse, I can ignore the subtitle.

I upgraded to the latest version and changed the command to:
ffmpeg -i "Rambo First Blood (1982) [2160p] [AAC5.1]-hevc.mkv" -map 0 -c copy -map -0:s:0 utput.mkv

I'm not deleting this in case someone has the same issue.

ffmpeg version 2024-08-01-git-bcf08c1171-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 13.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)

